# How do I ensure the empty list isn't printed (Scheme)?

Tags: scheme

I have this code:

```
(define graph `(A (B (C)) (D (E)) (C (E))))

(define (prog1 graph)
    (let ([seen `()])
      (define (sub g)
          (cond 
              [(member (car g) seen) `()]
              [else 
               (set! seen (cons (car g) seen))
               (cond
                 [(null? (cdr g)) (list (car g))]
                 [else
                  (cons (car g) (map sub (cdr g)))])])) 
    (sub graph)))
```

It prints a connected graph where all the nodes appear once. However, if a node has already been visited I return the empty list `` `() ``. This causes a problem with the output and I don't know how to fix it:

When running `(prog1 graph)` The current output is: `(A (B (C)) (D (E)) ())`

However, I want the output to be `(A (B (C)) (D (E)))`

Any hint on how I can modify the code to achieve this would be great.

Comment: `'()` appears in the output because you mix `cons` and `map`. Consider what happens to `(sub (A A A))`. Also what should happen to `(sub (A (A (B))))`? The way your code is written the output will probably be just `(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the empty lists only occur at the topmost level in the list, you could filter them out. Replace the last line in your procedure with this:

```
(filter (negate null?) (sub graph))
```

Or simply this:

```
(remove '() (sub graph))
```

If the empty lists occur at any nesting level, you can apply the same idea (filtering out empty lists) recursively, at each step in the traversal.